# How we send data from one component to another sibling component in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular8

I am developing an CRUD operation. While updating, on updateUser component I get data of user through service variable. But when I refresh edit page the data of user is undefined. Please suggest me a better solution of this.

I do not want to call api of users on editpage.

````
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
        this.editId = (Object.values(params))[0];
      }
    })
    if(this.traineeData) {
      this.traineeData = this.traineeService.traineeData;  // here I am getting data, but on refreshing it becomes undefined
    } else {
      this.traineeData = this.traineeService.traineeData;
    }
    console.log(this.traineeData)
  }


export class UserService {

  traineeData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTrainee() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.http.get('url').subscribe(
      res => resolve(res),
      err => reject(err));
    })
  }

  provideTraineeDataForEdit(data) {
    this.traineeData = data
    console.log(this.traineeData)
  }
}```
````

Comment: Just pass Id through `queryparams`  and then retrieve data against that id and patch values

Comment: I do that.I am facing this problem -  I am getting details of all users from traineeData. When I navigate to edit page, the input fields are filled up with their values. If I reload page, at that time traineeData bocomes undefined.For getting these details I have to again go to listing page and then on edit page.   I want to avoid this procedure.

Comment: Exactly to avoid that procedure I am saying just pass Id and then use that id to fetch data against that Id , Load data with that Id in `getAll()` method , everytime page refreshes it will be called again automatically. And make sure to store that id in a variable declared in current class where you are fetching details

Answer (score 1):

first of all, Angular is used to create SPA. So you do not refresh page, but in case your application requires it, it is obvious that on refresh data from service will get undefined because when you refresh you complete application gets reloaded.

So, in your case, if you still need the value after refresh and do not want to make an API call you can use browser local storage. With this you data will persist even after refresh but will be gone once the browser is closed.

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage  for more detail and implementation of local store.

Comment: I am getting details of all users from traineeData. When I navigate to edit page, the input fields are filled up with their values. If I reload page, at that time traineeData bocomes undefined.For getting these details I have to again go to listing page and then on edit page.

Comment: I think local storage is a better option for this.